# Convert access if statement to advantage code

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have the code below in an access query.  I want to convert that to a case or if in advantage sql.

I posted my case statement and its giving me an invalid operator > error code.  ive looked on the devzone for advantage database and it shows i can use the > operator.

any help would be great

Completed On-time: IIf([CompletedDate] Is Null Or Int([CompletedDate])>[DueDate],"No","Yes")

```
   case 
   when completeddate is null then 'No'
   when completeddate > duedate then 'No'
   else 'Yes'
   End as "CompletedDateCase"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
iff(completeddate is null or completeddate > duedate, "No", "Yes") as CompletedDateCase
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to convert a date column to an integer.

Oh, if you are trying to go the other way:

```
(CASE WHEN CompletedDate Is Null Or CAST(CompletedDate as INT) > DueDate
      THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes'
 END) as CompletedDateCase
```

You should be able to compare a date and a date/time:

```
(CASE WHEN CompletedDate Is Null Or CompletedDate > DueDate
      THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes'
 END) as CompletedDateCase
```

You might want to check if this matches the logic you actually want.  For instance, the time component might impact the results.

Comment: i used iff(completeddate is null or completeddate > duedate, "No", "Yes") as CompletedDateCase 
and im getting the following error 


poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: > -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 281 (line: 3 column: 31)

Comment: that int was in access and im not the developer that used that.  someone before me did this in access and im trying to get this into a view in advantage sql

Comment: @BrianK . . . The second query appears to be the one you want.

Comment: still getting an invalid operand for operator >

Comment: think i got it now.  completeddate is a date/time and duedate is date only.

Comment: used this 
CAST(completeddate as sql_date) > duedate